# When specific string appears print them every time they appear

Tags: bash, git-bash

When a specific string appears to print them every time they appear.

For example, if the `input_file.txt` as the following text

```
PerformanceINFO
            UVM_INFO_PERF ****NIB-FIB Axis Interface Per-packet Performance Report****
             interface_name            : NIB-FIB,
             payload_sizes (bytes)     : {1,2,3,4,5,6....10, }
             packet_datarate (bits/clk): {11,22,33,44,55,.....20, }


interface_name            : NIB-FIB,
                 payload_sizes (bytes)     : {100,202,303,405,5,6....10, }
                 packet_datarate (bits/clk): {11,22,33,44,55,.....20, }

interface_name            : NIB-FIB,
                 payload_sizes (bytes)     : {13,24,35,45,55,65....10, }
                 packet_datarate (bits/clk): {11,22,33,44,55,.....20, }
```

so what I am expecting is I want to print output as following every time "payload_size(byte)"  and "packet_datarate (bits/CLK) appears in my `input_file.txt` as shown below

```
Output_file.txt

payload_sizes (bytes)     : 1,2,3,4,5,6....10
packet_datarate (bits/clk):11,22,33,44,55,.....20

payload_sizes (bytes)     : 100,202,303,405,5,6....10
packet_datarate (bits/clk): 11,22,33,44,55,.....20

payload_sizes (bytes)     : 13,24,35,45,55,65....10
packet_datarate (bits/clk): 11,22,33,44,55,.....20
```

What I did so far is merging all of them but I want them to get printed as they appear

```
awk -F: '/packet_datarate/ { packt=packt""gensub(/[ {}]/,"","g",$2) } /payload_sizes/ { payl=payl""gensub(/[ {}]/,"","g",$2) } END { print "payload_sizes(bytes):,"payl;print "packet_datarate(bits/clk):,"packt }' input_file.txt >> output_file.txt
```

Comment: just `grep -F -e 'payload_sizes (bytes)' -e 'packet_datarate (bits/clk)' -e '^$'` will be close. i fear somebody will close this as duplicate of something

Comment: to fetch from input_file.txt and put it on output_file.txt code will be as following right 

grep -F -e 'payload_sizes (bytes)' -e 'packet_datarate (bits/clk)' -e '^$' input_file.txt >> output_file.txt

Comment: However I tried to run it but its printing only "payload-

Comment: However, I tried to run it but its printing only "payload_size (bytes)" and not "packet_datarate (bits/clk) "


grep -F -e 'payload_sizes (bytes)' -e 'packet_datarate (bits/clk)' -e '^$' rinput_file.txt >> output_file.csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 awk '/payload_sizes \(bytes\)/ { str=gensub(/(^[[:space:]]+)|[{}]/,"","g",$0);print substr(str,1,length(str)-2) } /packet_datarate \(bits\/clk\):/ { str=gensub(/(^[[:space:]]+)|[{}]/,"","g",$0);printf "%s\n\n",substr(str,1,length(str)-2) }' input_file.txt
```

Using awk (GNU awk in this case) If the "bytes" line is encountered, remove the leading spaces and {} and print. If the "bits/clk" lines is encountered, strip the leading spaces and print the line with an extra carriage return.

Answer (score 0):

Try this pipeline, it works

```
grep 'payload_sizes\|packet_datarate' input_file.txt | sed "s/{\|}//g"
```

The sed part is to remove } and {